# A way to extract IP:port;data occurances in a large text file?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find a way to extract all occurrences of IP:Port;Data in a large text file. 
Data inside the txt file is in the following format:

```
IP      :   Port    ;   IDM     [Random data]

10.255.74.66:4195;Wmr!1[Vaf3tgLpOTGtfhS]<br>
11.255.74.67:6741;Wmr2[Pc44bCM4ltw50]<br>
12.255.74.68:3951;Wmr#3a[eSTrTaiN2BzygX]<br>
14.255.74.69:3486;Wmr4b1#[Gytkt2JuH768LD]<br>
```

The output expected should be :

```
IP      :   Port    ;   IDM

10.255.74.66:4195;Wmr!1<br>
11.255.74.67:6741;Wmr2<br>
12.255.74.68:3951;Wmr#3a<br>
14.255.74.69:3486;Wmr4b1#<br>
```

After spending some hours searching for a solution i ended with this:

```
cat data.txt | grep -Po "(([0-1](\d\d?)?|2([0-4]\d?|5[0-5]?|[6-9])?|[3-9]\d?)\.){3}([0-1](\d\d?)?|2([0-4]\d?|5[0-5]?|[6-9])?|[3-9]\d?)(:([0-5](\d(\d(\d\d?)?)?)?|6([0-4](\d(\d\d?)?)?|5([0-4](\d\d?)?|5([0-2]\d?|3[0-5]?|[4-9])?|[6-9]\d?)?|[6-9](\d\d?)?)?|[7-9](\d(\d\d?)?)?))?" | sort | uniq >> results.txt
```

But is not working as expected. It only extract IP:port

If anyone has a solution to this I will be very gratefull.

Comment: what about just `^.*(?=\[)`?

Comment: Thanks... It works like a charm, I don't believe how simple it was.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to match everything you need, it's easier to match up until the first character you don't need.

**Following matches from the start of a line until <sub>(exclusive)</sub> the first square bracket**

```
^.*(?=\[)?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assert the start of the string `^` and then match not an opening bracket one or more times using a negated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[^[]+`

[`^[^[]+`](https://regex101.com/r/LGmVn9/1)